# How to access model-method?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a user that looks like this:

```
User = sequelize.define('user', {},{
    classMethods: {
        register: (params) => {
            var user = User.build(),
                fbprofile = userAttributes.build({name: 'fbprofile', value: params.fbprofile}),
                afterAllResolved = (results) =>
                {
                    return results[0]
                        .addUserAttributes([
                            results[1]
                        ]);
                };

            user.save();
            fbprofile.save();

            return sequelize.Promise.all([user, fbprofile])
                .then(afterAllResolved);

        },
        show: () => {
            this.getUserAttributes()
                .then((attributes) => {
                    return {
                        user: user,
                        attributes: attributes
                    };
                });
        }
        ...
```

And I try to do this:

```
app.get('/user/create',
    (req, res) => {
        User.register(req.query)
            .then((user) => {
                console.log(user.show);
                res.json('done');
            });
    }
```

For some reason user.show is undefined, why? I expect it to be a method.
Will i be able to use "this" in show to reference the current instance of the object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things that I noticed:

```
user.save();
fbprofile.save();

return sequelize.Promise.all([user, fbprofile])
  .then(afterAllResolved);
```

This doesn't seem right: both `user` and `fbprofile` are model instances, not promises. I think you want this:

```
return sequelize.Promise.all([ user.save(), fbprofile.save() ])
  .then(afterAllResolved);
```

Secondly, you're declaring `show` as a class method; in other words, you can use it as `User.show()` but *not* as `user.show()`. For that, you need to declare it as an instance method:

```
instanceMethods : {
  show: function() {
    return this.getUserAttributes() // return this promise!
      .then((attributes) => {
        return {
          user       : this, // `user` isn't defined here, I assume it's `this`
          attributes : attributes
        };
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, yes! however this.getUserAttributes, doesn't seem to be a function. console.log(this) insisde `show()` returns an empty object.

Comment: @Himmators this may be because of the fat arrow, I changed my answer. I assume that `getUserAttributes()` is also an instance method?

Comment: `getUserAttributes` is created because there is a hasMany connection to the userAttibutes-table, yes, removing the fat arrow seems to wok, but I don't get why...

Comment: @Himmators it's explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this).